# Need to set a default value for multiple input for list in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, user-input

I'm trying to get the default value if input is blank, how can I do that?

Output what I'm getting is for variable is blank if there is no user input.

```
Brand_default = 'ABC','XYZ'
cate_default = 'GKK','KKL','MKK','UKK'

Brand = list(input('Please enter Brand? (ABC/XYZ)= ').split(',') or Brand_default)
Cate = list(input('Please enter Category?GKK,KKL,MKK,UKK = ').split(',') or cate_default)
```

Comment: How about using an `if` statement? **If** the user input is empty, do this, otherwise do that.

Comment: “Blank”? Blank isn’t a possible output value here.

Comment: Hint: `split` on an empty string returns a list containing an empty string. A list containing an empty string is *not* empty.

Comment: without split user can not input multiple value @mkrieger1

Comment: I don't say that you shouldn't use `split`

Comment: You should make the defaults strings as well. Then you can simply do `Brand = (input(f'Please enter Brand? ({Brand_default}) = ') or Brand_default).split(',')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic needs to decide whether the value is empty, and then split if not. Unfortunately, this means your otherwise rather elegant `or` formulation won't work.

```
def split_or_default(prompt, default):
    response = input(prompt + " (" + "/".join(default) + ") ")
    if response == "":
        return default
    return response.split(",")

Brand = split_or_default(
    'Please enter Brand?',
    ['ABC','XYZ'])
Cate = split_or_default(
    'Please enter Category?',
    ['GKK','KKL','MKK','UKK'])
```

Notice also how the defaults are also lists now. I suppose your code could work with lists or tuples, but that seems like an unwelcome complication.

Tangentially, you should probably remove the "Please enter" part from the prompt. It's nice to be polite, but in user interfaces, it's actually more friendly to be concise.

Requiring commas between the values is also somewhat cumbersome. If some values could contain spaces, you need for the input to be unambiguous; but if these examples are representative, you could just as well split on whitespace.

In keeping with the [DRY Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) I refactored the repeated code into a function.

Comment: Hi can u help me as it did started taking input correctly but i not able to filter the data from dataframe based on it-  Final_Datanew.loc[(Final_Datanew['Brand'].isin(Brand)) & (Final_Datanew['Category'].isin(Cate)) ]  ---- @tripleee

Comment: Sorry, not a Pandas person. Generally, you should post a new question rather than try to solve a new problem in comments anyway. (But search before asking.)